# Angular Bootstrap Datepicker DateDisabled not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a problem with my angular bootstrap datepicker.
I am trying to disable dates dynamically but for some reason the dates doesn't get disabled when they should be.

Here are the options for my datepicker and disabled function.

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
    minDate: new Date(),
    startingDay: 1,
    dateDisabled: disabled
};
function disabled(data) {
    var mode = data.mode,
        date = data.date;
    if(mode === 'day'){
        $scope.disabledDates.forEach(function(disabledRange){
            var from = new Date(disabledRange.fromDate);
            var to = new Date(disabledRange.toDate);

            if(DateService.inRange(date, from, to)){
                console.log("disabled");
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am using popup calendar, when I open it disabled function is being called for each day in the calendar as expected and it returns true for each date that should be disabled but for some reason it doesn't disable them in the calendar.

Can someone try to point me in the right direction, I've tried making directives and decorators to refresh the calendar view but they haven't worked either.

Comment: Do you want to limit the selectable dates depending on one or two other dates selected? Why not just use the `maxDate` and `minDate` and bind them to an expression?

Comment: I'm making a rental service of sorts and I'm trying to limit the selectable dates for ranges where it has already been reserved.
maxDate and minDate doesn't accomplish what I am trying to do.

My code should work as it returns true for every day that should be disabled but for some reason it doesn't disable them in the datepicker.